# How to add shadow to menu drop-down list?

Tags: menu, javafx, shadow

In a menu bar, when we click a menu, there is a menu drop-down list containing some menu items. My question is how to add shadow to the menu drop-down list? Just like I see there is shadow in the combo box drop-down list in the default javafx implementation. Thanks ~

Comment: If you are using JavaFX2, you can have a look at [caspian.css](https://bitbucket.org/openjfxmirrors/openjfx-8-master-rt/src/89ee519f5c1a474e0121ce3b4e95b1f26142029f/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css) - at line 3199 is the drop shadow for the combo list. You can apply something similar to other controls in your own css. For Java 8 check [modena.css](https://bitbucket.org/openjfxmirrors/openjfx-8-master-rt/src/89ee519f5c1a474e0121ce3b4e95b1f26142029f/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css).

Comment: I have tried, but it does not affect for menu drop-down list. Though, effectively it works for combo box drop-down list... I used javaFX 2.2 , Kubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

```
yourDropDownMenu.setEffect(addLabelEffect());
```

Define the drop shadow in the controller class and check if its working. Here is a simple sample

```
private DropShadow addLabelEffect() {

    DropShadow ds = new DropShadow();
    ds.setSpread(0);
    ds.setOffsetY(1.0);
    ds.setOffsetX(1.0);
    ds.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    return ds;

}
```